# json multidimensional array listdown jquery for car shop

Tags: jquery, json

I'm trying to do a listdown selector for choose a car model by the user of my shop.  but not I access the models of the second trademark.
Specifically do not work from the Audi A3-A4 model.
I don't know what i'm doing wrong. 
I would appreciate a push.
Thanks in advance a lot !
attached code in jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uC8ft/1/

I think my error is in this code:

```
 $('#model').on('change', function(){
    console.log($(this).val() );
    for (var b=0; b < carJson.marca.length ; b++)    {     
        for ( var c=0; c < 2 ; c++) {

        //for ( var c=0; c < carJson.marca[b].model.length ; c++) {
            if(carJson.marca[b].model[c].id == $(this).val()){
         $('#eng').html('<option value="000">-Motorsss!-</option>');
         $.each(carJson.marca[b].model[c].engine, function (index, value) {
         $("#eng").append('<option value="' + value.id + '">' + value.name + '</option>');

        });              
      }
    }
   }
} );
```

more specifically, in the loops "for" or the last "each".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the inner loop

`for ( var c=0; c < 2 ; c++) {`

with

`for ( var c=0; c < carJson.marca[b].model.length ; c++) {`

Comment: Thank you very much, I couldn't find what i was doing wrong.  very useful reply. Thank you.